# python: how to create interactions between objects- reference to object doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, class, reference, simulation

I'm trying to create a bunch of objects that interact (neural population simulation) in non-identical ways- so one object might be connected to 2 other objects and some outside variable, another one would be connected to one other object and itself, etc, etc.

I'm very new at object oriented stuff. my approach is to have my class have a list `self.connections=[]` of all the connections that it has with other objects (i'm going to want to add up all the connections at some point), and method:

```
def addNewConnection(self,strength,source,name):
    newConnection=Connection(strength,source,name) # named tuple or class
    self.connections.append(newConnection)
```

then on each time step of the simulation i can compute the net input from all the different sources:

```
netInput+=[c.source * c.weight for c in self.connections]
```

but I can't figure out how to pass in the source as a reference, not a value! since the values are most likely changing as the simulation progresses. My guess is to do something re: mutable types, like making the value of source a 1 element list... but isn't that computationally expensive? EDIT: Also doesn't work.

Comment: You're going to have to decide when to recalculate the `netInput` anyway. There is no way to have `netInput` change as any of the `c.source` values change (and even if they were, it would be a waste of time to do that recalculation every time any value changed: do it when all the `c.source` values have changed.

Comment: _"I can't figure out how to pass in the source as a reference, not a value"_. parameters are always passed by reference. It's true that `def frob(x): x = whatever` doesn't modify the value of `x` outside the function. but that's more the fault of assignment than of function calls. You're on the right track with your "pass in a mutable type" idea. I don't think a one element list is much more expensive than, say, an integer.

Comment: Try to create a short, self-contained example that shows the behavior you're having trouble with.  That is, create a dummy "source" and a simple function and show what you are trying to do that doesn't work due to the reference/value problems you mentioned.  It is easier to respond to a specific example than to a general description.

Comment: What kind of thing is the `source`?

Comment: typically, an attribute of another object. this attribute is typically some float value that gets updated, ie Unit1.response could be a source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import namedtuple

Connection=namedtuple("Connection",["source","strength"])
class Unit(object):

# these first two methods just let me set up units and connections:
    def __init__(self,par=1, response=[0], connections=[]):
        self.par=par
        self.response=response
        self.connections=dict()#[]

    def receiveConnection(self,source,strength,label):
        # source is some other variable, strength is probably fixed but
        # i'd like it to be able to change, too
        #cx = Connection(label,source,strength)
        #self.connections.append(cx)
        self.connections[label]=Connection(source,strength)

# stuff that gets done iteratively through the sim      
    def update(self):
        netInput=0.
        # based on the value of all the sources and weights right now,
        for item in self.connections.itervalues():
            netInput+= item.source[0] * item.strength
        self.response[0] += self.par * netInput

if __name__=="__main__":
    Unit1 = Unit()
    Unit2 = Unit(response=[1])

    Unit1.receiveConnection(source=Unit2.response,strength=.5,label="U2toU1")
    Unit2.receiveConnection(source=Unit2.response,strength=-.5,label="negativeFeedback")

    for t in xrange(10):
        Unit1.update()
        print 'Unit1:    ' + str(Unit1.response)
        Unit2.update()
        print 'Unit2:    ' + str(Unit2.response)
```

This actually seems to work, it's just clunky as all heck (and it doesn't even have the legit functionality in there):

```
Unit1:    [0.5]
Unit2:    [0.5]
Unit1:    [0.75]
Unit2:    [0.25]
Unit1:    [0.875]
Unit2:    [0.125]
Unit1:    [0.9375]
Unit2:    [0.0625]
Unit1:    [0.96875]
Unit2:    [0.03125]
Unit1:    [0.984375]
Unit2:    [0.015625]
Unit1:    [0.9921875]
Unit2:    [0.0078125]
Unit1:    [0.99609375]
Unit2:    [0.00390625]
Unit1:    [0.998046875]
Unit2:    [0.001953125]
Unit1:    [0.9990234375]
Unit2:    [0.0009765625]
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're trying to build is a graph. Have a look at a graph library, such as [Python-Graph](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/) or [graph-tool](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/) to handle your data structure.

In this setup, you would have two data structures:

1. A graph where each of your objects is represented by a node in the graph, and your connections are the graph edges. Each node would have a string name to identify the object it represents.
2. A dictionary mapping the node names to the objects.

This setup would allow you to (fairly) easily manipulate your complex data structure without reimplementing code that already exists somewhere. It looks like you're already dealing with "weights" associated with these connections between objects, so a weighted graph seems like a natural way to organize them.

This approach would also completely bypass the issue you're currently having, because it would abstract the data structure out of your current objects. The classes you're currently writing wouldn't have to know what kind of data structure they're contained in. You could write a second class that contains both the string-to-object dictionary and the graph, which would give the rest of your application a single interface to the entire data structure without making your current classes overly complicated.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer. The reason I have not accepted this answer is that I want to learn (and asked a question about a problem in) Python, not graph theory :) while I believe you when you say this may solve my problem, it really doesn't go about showing how I could use these tools to do that. I also can't believe that it is supposed to be this difficult to have objects interact with each other by referring to each others' attributes-- this problem should have applications outside of my particular domain.

Comment: You're correct that the approach you've described could work, and the single element list method you mentioned is probably your best bet. However, I tried to steer you away for two reasons: 1) you said your list attempt didn't work, but you didn't give us enough details to help you debug it. If you share some code and more specific error messages, we could help you fix it. 2) I think the graph approach is a better abstraction and more more maintainable in the long-term. It also gives you access to a library of existing code, instead of you having to rewrite the traversal algorithms.

Comment: i am certainly intrigued, i just have no idea how to translate the algorithms into graphs.